# how to source tmux session_id into tmux

Tags: bash, shell, tmux

I have this:

```
export session_uuid="$(uuidgen)"

remove_session() {
  tmux kill-session -t "$session_uuid"
}

export -f remove_session

trap remove_session TERM INT SIGINT SIGTERM

source 'scripts/shell.sh'

echo "TMUX session id: $session_uuid"
tmux new -d -s "$session_uuid"
tmux split-window -h -t "${session_uuid}.0"
```

but the problem is that neither the env var `session_uuid` or the bash function `remove_session` are inherited into TMUX.

How can I can get this functionality? (I want to be able to call "remove_session" from any TMUX pane.)

Resourcing my bashrc file won't really do the trick, because session_id is created on the first source no the source after TMUX is running...

Comment: Where do you "have this"? Is this in your bashrc or profile or do you call it manually?

Comment: I definitely don't want to call it every time bashrc loads...the above is in a separate script I call when I need it

Comment: Then please edit your question and explain that and especially explain how you call it. Do you execute it or run it? Before or after starting the tmux session? Have you tried just having this in `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` instead?

Comment: yes the function could go into bash_profile, my King, but the session_id couldn't? Because the session_id is created before we jump into tmux, all by definition. So ultimately we have a difficult situation on our hands because we got one hand tied...

notice that I edited the question to be about the tmux session_id instead. Now, maybe we can grab the session_id from inside tmux, but ultimately this question is more about a clever way to access env vars

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1424154/432690) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

In theory it would be doing this:

```
tmux new -d -s "$session_uuid"
tmux set-option -g update-environment "remove_session session_uuid"
```

the bash function was *not* passed down to tmux, but the env var *was*, not sure why that is.

Comment: Use `env | grep remove_session` to see how Bash passes the exported function as an environment variable.